# HTML 5 <audio> - Play file at certain time point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have a simple auto playing snippet that plays the audio file however I was wondering either in JavaScript or as an attribute play that file at a certain time (ex. 3:26).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myAudio=document.getElementById('audio2')
    myAudio.oncanplaythrough=function(){this.play();}
</script>

<audio id="audio2" 
       preload="auto" 
       src="file.mp3" 
       oncanplaythrough="this.play();">
</audio>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where is this "oncanplaythrough" attribute coming from? It's not in any standard.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A few things... your script will first need to be *after* the audio tag.

Also you don't need the `oncanplaythough` attribute on the audio tag since you're using JavaScript to handle this.

Moreover, `oncanplaythrough` is an **event**, not a method. Let's add a listener for it, which will instead use `canplaythough`. Take a look at this:

```
<audio id="audio2" 
   preload="auto" 
   src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg" >

   <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>

<script>
  myAudio=document.getElementById('audio2');
  myAudio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    this.currentTime = 12;
    this.play();
  });
</script>
```

And finally, to start the song at a specific point, simply set `currentTime` before you actually play the file. Here I have it set to 12 seconds so it will be audible in this example, for 3:26 you would use 206 (seconds).

Check out the live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mNPCP/4/

---

**EDIT**: It appears that `currentTime` may improperly be implemented in browsers *other* than Firefox. According to resolution of this [filed W3C bug](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12982), when `currentTime` is set it should then fire the `canplay` and `canplaythrough` events. This means in our example, Firefox would play the first second or so of the audio track indefinitely, never continuing playback. I came up with this quick workaround, let's change

```
this.currentTime = 12;
```

to test to see if it has already been set, and hence preventing the `canplaythrough` to get called repeatedly:

```
if(this.currentTime < 12){this.currentTime = 12;}
```

This interpretation of the spec is still currently being disputed, but for now this implementation should work on most modern browsers with support for HTML5 audio.

The updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mNPCP/5/

Comment: I don't see canplaythrough as any event in any standard. Where do you find that?

Comment: the `oncanplaythrough` event-handler was recently added, as part of the [29 March 2012 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/spec.html#scripting.attr.oncanplaythrough)

Comment: OK, so WARNING! oncanplaythrough does not work, and is not documented, in any browser but IE and is only five months old and in draft status alone.

Comment: Only documented in IE? Really? Hard to believe! Haha. `canplaythrough` (or `oncanplaythough` when used as an attribute) appears to work fine in Chrome and Firefox, and is [documented here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/canplaythrough)

Comment: Note I said "oncanplaythrough" which is not documented on MDN, nor Opera or Webkit. If you can find it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `oncanplaythrough` property does not exist in Chrome, at least as of version 23.

Comment: Oddly enough it is lacking in any documentation, yet it still appears to work. From what I gathered from some sources such as [this filed Chromium bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73609), it does exist, but has been improperly implemented

Comment: I've provided a simple workaround in the latter half of my answer

Answer (score 39):

The best way to do this is to use the Media Fragment URI specification.  Using your example, suppose you want to load the audio starting at 3:26 in.

```
<audio id="audio2" 
       preload="auto" 
       src="file.mp3#t=00:03:26" 
       oncanplaythrough="this.play();">
</audio>
```

Alternatively, we could just use the number of seconds, like `file.mp3#t=206`.

You can also set an end time by separating the start from the end times with a comma.  `file.mp3#t=206,300.5`

This method is better than the JavaScript method, as you're hinting to the browser that you only want to load from a certain timestamp.  Depending on the file format and server support for ranged requests, it's possible for the browser to download only the data required for playback.

See also:

- [MDN Documentation - Specifying playback range](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range)
- [W3C Media Fragments URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/)

Comment: Can someone please tell me why this method is not working the second time? I'm playing the audio on click but the second time the button is clicked, the audio plays but the #t=begintime,endtime not working

Comment: This works for me: 
<audio
 :src="blobUrl + '#t=00:03:26'"
controls
ref="foo"
 preload="auto"
></audio>

Comment: If the "end" url arg is provided an is effective, the "ended" event won't fire on Chrome

Comment: @MadeinMoon It's not ineffective, it's just that the `ended` event doesn't fire under that circumstance (sadly).

Answer (score -4):

1. Create a button that when clicked it plays the audio/video
2. Test that audio playing when you click the button if it works to hide the button and
3. Click button when page loads

   ```
   window.onload =function(){
       document.getElementById("btn").click();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't have anything to do with the question being asked, which is how to have it start at a certain timestamp.