# Show an image when HTML5 <audio> starts to play

Tags: css, html, html5-audio

I have website with background music and single image. I want image to be hidden until music starts and maybe even have somekind of loading message until audio starts autoplay.
please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12030459/1915428). 
Obviously you have to change the function attached to 'canplaythrough' to suit your needs, e.g. adding something like:

```
$("#imageID").css("display", "block");
```

Answer (score 0):

First set image hidden via CSS.

You need to listen to Javascript events `<audio>` element is firing:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Media_events

Then in Javascript code, catch the event you want to honour and dynamically make the image visible
in the event handler using jQuery.show or similar DOM element style manipulation:

http://api.jquery.com/show/