# Specifiying start time and end time for playing audio file in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to use JavaScript to play an audio file on a webpage.

I have an article that I want to be read out from the mp3 file. As the article is being read out by the audio I want to highlight the text of the article that is being read out by the audio.

Also I want to be able to provide each sentence as a link where the user can simply click a particular sentence and the mp3 file starts where that sentence begins and ends when that sentence ends.

Comment: Assuming you are using HTML5 audio, please check the answer in the below stackoverflow question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029509/html-5-audio-play-file-at-certain-time-point

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late but I have to do this right now. I'm using this https://github.com/westonruter/html5-audio-read-along

It is very easy to use. Here you can listen to the mp3 and reading the text with the current word highlighted. You can perform various actions as clicking on a specific word or playing with audio controls and it works fine.
But if you are using mp3 files remember not to have a variable bitrate because it does not work with the currentTime audio value.
Hope it helps!