# Playing mp3 attach href link to audio control

Tags: html

I've created a link to play mp3 from and certain point and end at a certain point

```
<audio id="sample" src="Hard To Say I'm Sorry.mp3" controls preload></audio>

<a href="javascript:playSegment(10, 15);">Play1</a>

<script>
var audio = document.getElementById('sample');
var segmentEnd;

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (){
if (segmentEnd && audio.currentTime >= segmentEnd) {
    audio.pause();
}   
console.log(audio.currentTime);
}, false);

function playSegment(startTime, endTime){
segmentEnd = endTime;
audio.currentTime = startTime;
audio.play();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question, how do I put the href "Play1" link into the audio control?

Comment: possible duplicate: [HTML 5 <audio> - Play file at certain time point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029509/html-5-audio-play-file-at-certain-time-point)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, please read question

Comment: Use CSS. The audio control does not accept HTML inside it (the only HTML valid is for the fallback when `<audio>` is not supported). With CSS and `position` property you can move the link to the part you want

Comment: Have you got an example please?

Comment: Is it possible to have the equivalent of this javascript:playSegment(10, 15);" for the audio control?