# How to create bookmark for an Audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am new to web dessign, can anyone help me to create a bookmark for an audio file playing with HTML audio tag:

```
<audio control> 
 <source src="myAudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

For example, audio is at 2 minutes 30 seconds and I press the bookmark button, it should save this location. Next time I should be able to play from the same location.

Comment: You might store the bookmarked times and use them to [start playing the audio file at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029509/html-5-audio-play-file-at-certain-time-point).

Comment: The comment above reads to me more like an "Answer" than a question that asks the OP for clarifying information. If it were listed as an "Answer", I would vote it up as it contains useful information.