# A button at html to trigger an autoplay audio at exact time

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I have an `setInterval(function()` that I want to use a html button to trigger it by clicking to start autoplay an audio at an exact time.
The timer works ok as I’ve tested by using an alert. Please advise if the below codes are ok to do an autoplay audio function?
thanks

html

```
<div id="time"></div>
  <audio controls style="display: none;">
     <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
 </audio>
```

javascript

```
setInterval(function() {
    var d = new Date(),
        hours = d.getHours(),
        min = d.getMinutes(),
        sec = d.getSeconds();
    if (hours === 16 && min === 25 && sec === 01) {
        var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]
        audio.play()
        audio.style.display = 'block'
    }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: you need to play audio every 1000ms?

Comment: to set time from check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12030459/14135825)

Comment: what exactly isn't working in your code?

Comment: The audio wont auto-play at the exact time. I’ve asked at my previous post and one user said it needs user to do an interaction to trigger the auto-play action. So I wonder if a button to trigger the `setInterval(function()`  will works? thanks