# Audiotag time control (#t=5,6) not working second time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55583936/16444630), To begin playing an audio at a certain time, we can use `#t=begintime,endtime` after the link.

This is working for me but only the first time.The second time, the **audio is playing but  not in the specified time.**

Like this:

```js
 function drainwater(){
       document.getElementById("drain").play();
     }
```

```html
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Kitchen_sink_draining_water.ogg#t=5,6" id="drain"></audio>   
   


<button onclick='drainwater()'> Drain </button>
```

The second time, the audio is playing longer than I expected.
What is the problem?
How can I overcome this?

---

As a workaround, I tried using a timer and pausing the audio after a certain time.

Like this:

```js
function drainwater(){
       document.getElementById("drain").play();
     }
     
     
 function pause(){
       document.getElementById("drain").pause();
     }
```

```html
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Kitchen_sink_draining_water.ogg" id="drain"></audio>   
   


<button onclick='drainwater();setTimeout(pause, 2000)'> Drain </button>
```

(An advice for those who may be using this solution: Don't forget to remove the #t=5,6 from the link or this will not work.)

This maybe enough  for homogenous audios like that of 2 minutes of raining audio- there is no difference between the first 10 seconds and the second 10 seconds- so we can use this method to play it for a specified amount of time.

But for general audios , this does not work. The second time the button is clicked, the audio is not starting from the specified position.

So Why is this happening? What can we do to play the audio at the specific time again and again on button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like at least Chrome and Firefox need the URL to be set again in order to do what you want. If you change your `drainwater()` function like this it should work.

```
function drainwater(){
    const $drain = document.getElementById("drain");

    $drain.onpause = () => $drain.src = $drain.src;
    $drain.play();
}
```

I'm not sure though if this is a bug or the intended behavior.

Comment: Thanks.. But can you show a Code snippet or something, I am new to web development and is not familiar with jquery. Or better, can you provide a javascript only solution?

Comment: I tried putting this function but with no succcess. Shows error: "drainwater is not defined"

Comment: Hi, it's a JavaScript only solution. I used a `$` prefixed variable name. You can replace that with a name that you like. The first snippet that you provided above contains a `drainwater()` function. It should work if you replace that function with the version from my answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, But I tried that, not working. Shows an error: "drainwater not defined" .Thats why I doubted it was jquery in the first place.

Comment: The error implies that the function is somehow not defined (or not reachable). Did you maybe rename it?

Comment: No, I only replaced my drainwater() function with the function you provided.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that there is a typo in the code snippet above. It misses an equals sign. I will go ahead and fix. Sorry for that.

Comment: Great, I'm happy to hear that.